# Unable to connect to remote Oracle database using DBeaver

Tags: oracle, jdbc, dbeaver

I am trying to connect to a remote Oracle db from my mac using DBeaver.

Dbeaver version I am using is: 5.1.3

I installed the ojdbc6.jar file from the below link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html

as instructed by the DBeaver tool. I added the above file in the driver manager window.

When I try to connect to the database I get the following error(dbeaver-debug.log):

```
Connection failed (oracle_thin-16161616-16161616)
2018-07-21 13:16:06.749 - org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCException: Connection has timed out
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCException: Connection has timed out
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:157)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.oracle.model.OracleDataSource.openConnection(OracleDataSource.java:133)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCExecutionContext.connect(JDBCExecutionContext.java:86)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.initializeMainContext(JDBCRemoteInstance
```

If anyone has suggestions as to how I can debug this issue, would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to connect via other tools (like SQL Developer)? if no then please try that as well. There can be multiple reasons for connection timeout. It is also possible that port in remote system is not accessible.

Comment: I tried SQL Developer as well. I get the same error. I am pretty sure the port is accessible.

Comment: Also, my colleagues with Windows system are able to connect with the same user credentials.

Comment: Please more details how you are trying to connect. I can't answer based on one exception.